# Non-integer dependent variable in negative binomial models

Tags: r, regression, count-data, negative-binomial-distribution

I have non-nested count data that I've interpolated from one area to another based on the proportion of the area that lays in each.  This is ZIP codes to counties, so most nest cleanly, with a few around the edges needing to be distributed in this way.  I'm aware that it would be better to propagate this uncertainty through the model (for instance Bannerjee Carlin and Gelfand, Chapter 6, Section 2), but that's way, way out of scope for this project for now, and I believe the error will be quite small.

This apportionment in proportion to area leaves me with a reasonable distribution of "counts" :

```
         0          1      (1,5]     (5,10]   (10,250] 
      0.30       0.35       0.22       0.06       0.06
```

The NBD models I've run on this have successfully converged, and report parameter estimates in the same basic ballpark as a Poisson regression on the same data.  It does return a warning message about non-integer values, though.

Is there any bias that results from running a negative binomial regression on count data that is non-integer?  Specifically, I'm doing this in R, using  `MASS::glm.nb`.